# Possible bug in seaborn residuals/Joint plots?

Tags: python, seaborn

I tried the following two options for plotting my regression model's residuals:

```
ax = sns.jointplot(data=df,x="PS",y='residuals',ax=True,kind='resid',marginal_ticks=True,lowess=True)
ax = sns.jointplot(data=df,x="PS",y='residuals',ax=True,kind='reg',marginal_ticks=True,lowess=True)
```

sns.residplot gives the same output as jointplot with the kind='resid' option set.

However, they each give a different lowess output and it looks like the residuals have been rotated around the y axis at y=0 when using `kind=resid`. The same data was used in both cases.

The residuals are plotted in both graphs, but they are wrong in the one with kind='resid'. Could this be a bug in the resid code? Even if it was a standardisation process applied, the residuals shouldn't be getting shifted from negative to positive.

[image: kind="resid"]

[image: kind="reg"]

Comment: Could you please try to make the example reproducible? Either by generating some dummy test data or using one of seaborn's example datasets?

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: Why do you think the `kind='resid'` plot is wrong? How should it look like? How did you calculate the residuals? Could you please add some reproducible data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying axes-level functions are `sns.regplot` and `sns.residplot`. The example data used in the question's post seems to use y-values which are close to normal distributed around zero, which makes it rather hard to see what is happening.

The code below uses the `Gentoo` species of the `penguins` dataset.

The `regplot` at the left shows the original data with a regression line. The  y-values are all positive, and the regression line has an upward slope.

The `residplot` at the right shows the data with the regression line subtracted. The y-values are positive where the original data are above the regression line, and negative below.  The `residplot` helps to assess whether the regression (linear in this case) is a suitable fit.

The linked [tutorial post](https://www.statisticshowto.com/residual-plot/) and video might be helpful to better understand the residual plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
penguins = penguins[penguins['species'] == 'Gentoo']
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(14, 4), sharex=True)
sns.regplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("regplot")
sns.residplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("residplot")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot vs sns.residplot]

If your input data are already residuals, both plots seem to be very similar:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins').dropna()
penguins = penguins[penguins['species'] == 'Gentoo']
x = penguins['bill_length_mm']
y = penguins['bill_depth_mm']
regr = stats.linregress(x, y)
y -= regr.slope * x + regr.intercept  # calculate the residuals

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))
sns.regplot(x=x, y=y, lowess=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('regplot')
sns.residplot(x=x, y=y, lowess=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('residplot')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot vs sns.residplot with residuals]

Comment: Could you clarify your question, for example using the residual data from the updated answer?

Comment: This is a perfect answer to the question as I understand it!

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for your great answer.  I realised I must have been using the equation wrongly. I had calculated the residuals before plotting with each of the reg and resid options of jointplot, I think that using the resid option meant that a further calculation was being done to calculate the residuals between the x-axis values and the already calculated residuals. I'll test this on my data on Monday. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your help. I've accepted your answer